# Is it ok to connect septic overflow line to a concrete box which has incoming from kitchen and bathroom line?

Tags: bathroom, concrete, kitchen-sink, septic

I have a precast concrete box like the one in below and this have three inlets and one outlet.

[image]

- outlet  -> Takes the water to near by canal
- Inlet 1 -> Kitchen sink outlet is connected with this
- Inlet 2 -> Bathroom drain outlet is connected with this.
- Inlet 3 -> As of now it's not is use.

I'm thinking of connecting the septic tank overflow pipe to the 3rd inlet.

But are there any health risks associated with this ?

Just wondering if pathogens , virus , bacteria etc.. can crawl through kitchen , bathroom line and cause health issue ?

Or is there any disinfectant tablet that I can drop into the box and that would take care of the germs ?

FYI:

Neither bathroom nor kitchen line has P trap so far , I think point of having p or s trap is to stop the toxic gas from coming in but I don't have gas issue.. the water seal in the trap is not gonna handle germ issue anyways right ?

Someone please help me understand.

Comment: Your location in the world will help a bit.  In most places dumping/draining that water into a canal/water course will be illegal.  P-traps prevent sewer gas smells from coming up from the drain pipes/tanks.

Comment: "Just wondering if pathogens , virus , bacteria etc.. can crawl through kitchen , bathroom line and cause health issue ?"    I'd be more concerned about septic overflow going into a canal.

Comment: I worry about snakes, the other stuff a doctor can handle.

Comment: That will depend how do you isolate
Normally you would not mix those two togethe
Cross contamination is a problem

Comment: What do you mean by "septic tank overflow?"

Comment: The excess water that comes out of septic tank .. because it has reached the capacity

Comment: @JACK - The town doesn't have any underground sewage system so the filtered overflowing water from septic tank is allowed to be discharged into this particular drainage canal

Comment: If you just piped your septic overflow in there, how would you ever know when the septic fills up and needs to be pumped?

Comment: @brhans - The septic tank is big enough , usually once in 5 years we can pump it out using septic tankers. But right now the situation is I have to pump out 3 to 4 times a year depending on the rainfall on particular year.  The ground is clay and it has high water level table , in a way I'm screwed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NZ, the overflow from the septic tank must not go to waterways. It must be spread on land with vegetation where it can evaporate and be further processed by microbes. I would think the regulations are the same where you are. Please check first.

In 1995, when we got our first system, they were advertised that you could drink that water. But my supplier refused to drink it. That bravado faded quickly.

If you did take it to waterways, as one of my friends has, you will probably find that it will start looking yucky and stink. The pathogens are a problem, but so is the fact that it is nutrient rich.